# Return collections lists of paths between different lengths paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm newly with cypher language. My problem is that i want return collection lists of paths between two (or more) nodes, which one path is longer than another. At the moment i have query

```
START startNode=node(251), endNode=node(4609) with (startNode)<-[*]-(endNode) as paths RETURN paths
```

But this query return just one list instead of two(or more)

i mean:

```
path1: a1->a2->a3->a4->a5,
path2: a1->a2->a3,
pathx: a1->a2->a3->a4
```

as result

neo4j version: 3.2.6

Comment: Can you add the criteria you're using for which nodes you want to match? Right now you're only providing explicit ids for start and end nodes. You can match to nodes based on labels and properties, and by adding an index on that label/property you can make that lookup very quick. Also, don't use the START clause, that's been deprecated. Have you read through the [developer manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/) yet?

Comment: I want match all nodes between two given. It dosent matter about criteria, the start node is always with id 251 and i give endNode always as param in variable (using java api). I know about providing matching with labels and node propertis.

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear what you want here. This is how you can collect lists of paths between those nodes: `MATCH path = (startNode)<-[*]-(endNode) WHERE id(startNode) = 251 and id(endNode) = 4609 RETURN collect(path)`
`

Comment: Ive got solution to my problem with function "START startNode = node({startId})
MATCH paths = (startNode)-[*]->(n) WHERE n.name = {name}
RETURN nodes(paths) as nodes" which giving me as result lists of paths between nodes. thanks for your interest!